# Needing Instant (1-2 minutes) API / IPN for bitcoin payments

Tags: php

Basically I'm creating a autobuy in PHP.
I'm currently using coinpayments.net but their payments take 1-12 hours to send (which defeats the object of my autobuy). I'm needing to know of any way I can allow my payments to be done after 1-2 minutes so I can send the buyer their email with their order automatically.

I wrote to coinpayments.net and am waiting for a reply. 
This should help you understand what I'm needing:

> I'm creating a autobuy shop and am using your API / IPN to get callbacks from the users payments to determine the status (successful, or unsuccessful) payment. The problem is that when a user pays the bitcoins to the address on the autobuy, (in coinpayments), it takes about 6-12 hours for the payment to clear. This defeats the whole object of my website (an autobuy). Is there any way I can make payments be completed after 1-2 minutes if a user actually does pay correctly ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's both 1) something concerning customer relationship with a company 2) it seeks for alternatives, which is "product or service reviews are off topic"

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your payment processor (coinpayments.net) is trying to construct bitcoin transactions with with lower fees, and therefore de-prioritizing confirmation times.  Perhaps their API offers the ability for you to prioritize your transactions by paying extra on the fee.  I know blockchain.info allows you to specify a fee if you are using their wallet API.  I'm sure others do as well.

Alternatively, you could run your own wallet/node and construct your transactions yourself with a higher fee.  It's a lot more effort, but depending on what you are trying to accomplish, it might be worth your time.

In any case, keep in mind that the bitcoin network averages a 10-minute block time, but does not guarantee it.  On top of that, the best rule of thumb is to allow for 6 blocks blocks of confirmation before considering a transaction irreversible.  For most payment systems, the values being transferred are so low that it's not necessary to wait for 6 blocks.  There are even plenty of types of purchases where so-called "zero-confirmation transactions" are perfectly acceptable.  This is what you will need to use if you want to send your email in less than 10 minutes.  You will have to judge for yourself how many confirmations you need, and what level of risk you are willing to accept.